# How can I redirect matching lines to a file, and non-matching lines to a different file?

Tags: text-processing, grep, tee

Is there a script/program/utility already available for the following requirement in a optimised way?

```
someCommand |
   tee >(grep "pattern" > LinesWhichMatch) |
   grep -v "pattern" > LinesWhichDoesNotMatch
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `awk` for that.

```
command | awk '{ if (/pattern/) { print > "match" } else { print > "nomatch" } }'
```

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with `awk` but at what point does it evaluade the `>` ? If it's evaluated each time the conditional applies, you'd wind up with two one-line files...

Comment: @Shadur `>` prints all output to the file, overwriting existing files. It isn't evaluated in such a way that it will result in any new lines overwriting old output from the same instance of `awk`. That is, if there are multiple matches, the file "match" will contain each match separated by `OFS`. The difference between `>` and `>>` exists in treatment of existing files.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a `sed` example:
Note: sed's `w` command will overwrite an existing file each time the script is run, but only if that particular write command is triggered; hence the `rm`

```
rm -f file-{yes,not}  
sed -ne '/pattern/bY; w file-not' -e 'b; :Y; w file-yes' file
```

Comment: Nice. Without branching: `sed -n '/PATTERN/p;//! w file-not' infile >file-yes`

Comment: Is there a `sed` version that also allows a substitution to happen on the matched lines? I can't figure out how to add an `s` command...

Answer (score 6):

You can append files in awk:

```
awk '{if (/pattern/) print >>"matched"; else print >>"unmatched"; }
```

or shorter:

```
awk '{print >>(/pattern/?"matched":"unmatched")}'
```

Comment: His example shows that he wants to overwrite the files if they exist, not append.